# How to get path to web resource from within EJB?

Tags: java, web-applications, ejb

This is my first post on StackOverflow, so let me know if I'm breaking any rules.

As for the question:

I have a JBOSS project divided as follows:

```
myproject
  -myproject-ear
  -myproject-ejb
     -mypackage
       -myQuartzClass.java
  -myproject-web
     -src
        -main
          -webapp
             -protected
                -sql
                  -mySqlQuery.sql
```

Thing is, I need to get the path (and then read the file) to "mySqlQuery.sql") from within the "MyQuartzClass.java". Is it possible? I know I can use FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRealPath from within a ManagedBean, but can I use something similar from within my EJB classes?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least for WAR deployments, you can have a ContextListener load some information into a static field of a non-@Startup-annotated EJB. There's a code sample at https://github.com/IanDarwin/GetWebFilesInEJB.git

I have not tested it on the legacy EAR deployment; if it doesn't work there, might give some people the incentive to simplify their lives a bit :-)